# Cannot inflate class after move from library project to jar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-library

I decided to switch from having library projects to having JARs in my libs directory. This worked fine for every library except the [DragSortListView library](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) i'm using. When i run my application i get an `InflateException` on the `DragSortListView` class that has to be inflated. I had to change the XML layout so i could use the attributes for the `DragSortListView` (the only change I made is to the xmlns:dslv line). It's also worth noting that i can use the `DragSortListView` class in java files

XML layout (library as project):

```
 <com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.package.myprojectpackage"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
        dslv:drag_enabled="true"
        dslv:drag_scroll_start="1"
        dslv:float_alpha="1.0"
        dslv:float_background_color="@color/Transparent"
        dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
        dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
        dslv:drag_handle_id="@+id/sabnzbd_queue_drag_handle"
        dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
        dslv:use_default_controller="true" />
```

XML layout (library as JAR):

```
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mobeta.android.dslv"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="1"
    dslv:float_alpha="1.0"
    dslv:float_background_color="@color/Transparent"
    dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    dslv:drag_handle_id="@+id/sabnzbd_queue_drag_handle"
    dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
    dslv:use_default_controller="true" />
```

InflateException (Library as JAR):

```
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-06 15:25:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(22907):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
```

If anyone can explain why the class can't be found in XML files and possibly give a solution on how to fix that it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: any Android project that has resources and uses the resource reference system cannot be packaged as a jar. It has to be an Android Library for the R.java file to be generated correctly and the resources to be resolved. i.e. `@color/Transparent`

Comment: I can't find a reference for that "fact" so leaving it as a comment!

Comment: @Blundell Thanks for the explaination! Maybe you could add this link and leave it as an answer anyway?

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#considerations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any Android project that has resources and uses the resource reference system cannot be packaged as a jar. It has to be an Android Library for the R.java file to be generated correctly and the resources to be resolved. i.e. `@color/Transparent`

Reference:

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#considerations